# How to add Alpine Linux repositories when their domain is expired?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, whois, alpine-package-keeper

Today, I was trying to build a Docker container using Alpine Linux 3.2. However, the `apk` command was not successful during building the container image because it could not retrieve the `APKINDEX` file.

I tried to add other `dl-` links to the Dockerfile recipe with no success:

```
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules
RUN echo "http://dl-1.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "http://dl-5.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    echo "http://dl-6.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

It seems that the domain associated with alpinelinux.org has been expired yesterday, and therefore the servers were not accessible via their names.

Is there any way to retrieve the actual IP addresses of the `dl-` servers to be added to the Dockerfile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found was:

1. Use the Domain History Checker from `WhoIsRequest` to determine the latest working name server associated to one of `dl-` servers, for example `dl-6.alpinelinux.org`:

   http://whoisrequest.com/history/

   The result was `ns2.alpinelinux.org`.
2. Then, use a regular `nslookup` service, such as `http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php`, along with `ns2.alpinelinux.org` and `dl-6.alpinelinux.org`, to get the actual IP of the repository. Finally, I arrived to:

   Name:   dl-6.alpinelinux.org,
   Address: 107.181.185.116
3. Now, the repository line in the Dockerflile looks like:

   RUN echo "http://107.181.185.116/alpine/v3.2/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \

That is all.