# Docker composer build error: ERROR: unable to select packages

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker composer build` or `docker compose build --no-cache` I get below error.

First I thought it was a network problem. But I tested the container does have internet access by placing a ping command in the docker file, which successfully receives a ping response.

What is the issue, and how can I solve it?

```
Step 6/16 : RUN apk add --upgrade --no-cache     acl     bash     bash-doc     bash-completion     autoconf     icu-dev     libxml2-dev     mysql-dev     pcre     php7-ctype     php7-fileinfo     php7-gd     php7-intl     php7-json     php7-mbstring     php7-openssl     php7-simplexml     php7-tokenizer     php7-xml     php7-bcmath     php7-pdo     php7-pdo_mysql     freetype-dev     libjpeg-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     nodejs     patch     tidyhtml-dev     imap-dev     libzip-dev     git     python2
 ---> Running in 1ae4ac5b75b6
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  php7-bcmath (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-bcmath]
  php7-ctype (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-ctype]
  php7-fileinfo (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-fileinfo]
  php7-gd (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-gd]
  php7-intl (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-intl]
  php7-json (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-json]
  php7-mbstring (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-mbstring]
  php7-openssl (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-openssl]
  php7-pdo (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-pdo]
  php7-pdo_mysql (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-pdo_mysql]
  php7-simplexml (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-simplexml]
  php7-tokenizer (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-tokenizer]
  php7-xml (no such package):
    required by: world[php7-xml]
  python2 (no such package):
    required by: world[python2]
ERROR: Service 'application' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --upgrade --no-cache     acl     bash     bash-doc     bash-completion     autoconf     icu-dev     libxml2-dev     mysql-dev     pcre     php7-ctype     php7-fileinfo     php7-gd     php7-intl     php7-json     php7-mbstring     php7-openssl     php7-simplexml     php7-tokenizer     php7-xml     php7-bcmath     php7-pdo     php7-pdo_mysql     freetype-dev     libjpeg-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     nodejs     patch     tidyhtml-dev     imap-dev     libzip-dev     git     python2' returned a non-zero code: 14
```

EDIT:

Tried suggestion of @Mureinik to use `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.15` instead of `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine`. When I tied this, it gets past the initial error. But I get a different error instead. See below.

```
#0 69.23 creating libtool
#0 69.26 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
#0 69.32 configure: patching config.h.in
#0 69.32 configure: creating ./config.status
#0 69.36 config.status: creating config.h
#0 69.39 /bin/sh /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/libtool --mode=compile cc -I"/usr/include" -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c -o iconv.lo 
#0 69.45 mkdir .libs
#0 69.45  cc -I/usr/include -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/iconv.o
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c: In function 'zm_startup_miconv':
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:284:4: error: '_libiconv_version' undeclared (first use in this function)
#0 69.60   284 |    _libiconv_version >> 8, _libiconv_version & 0xff);
#0 69.60       |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:284:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c: In function '_php_iconv_appendl':
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:181:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'libiconv'; did you mean 'iconv'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
#0 69.60   181 | #define iconv libiconv
#0 69.60       |               ^~~~~~~~
#0 69.60 /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c:453:8: note: in expansion of macro 'iconv'
#0 69.60   453 |    if (iconv(cd, (char **)&in_p, &in_left, (char **) &out_p, &out_left) == (size_t)-1) {
#0 69.60       |        ^~~~~
#0 69.64 make: *** [Makefile:192: iconv.lo] Error 1
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install intl zip pcntl pdo_mysql iconv opcache soap tidy imap bcmath &&     php -r 'ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(-1); iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "foobar");']: exit code: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the `php7-bcmath` package, but it seems the same issue occurs in most of them.
This package has builds for Alpine 3.13 through 3.15, but the latest Alpine is 3.16, which doesn't have a build for this package yet. You can wait until it's available, or lock down your Dockerfile to a specific Alpine version that has a build for this package, e.g.:

```
FROM alpine:3.15
```

**EDIT:**
According to additional information supplied in the comments, the dockerfile uses `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine`, which internally uses `FROM alpine`. Instead, you could use a version that locks down to a specific Alpine version:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.15
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Strangely, on my colleague's computer it does work. Any idea why? He also used the `--no-cache flag`.

Comment: Docker file uses `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` can I find a drop in replacement with Alpine 3.15? Or how would I do that. When I use `FROM alpine:3.15` I get other errors.

Comment: @Akif that's `7.4-fpm-alpine` that uses the latest Alpine. You could use `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.15` instead in order to lock it down to a specific Alpine version. I'll edit this into the answer too, for posterity.

Comment: I tried the suggestion, thanks. It gets past the initial error, but I get another error instead. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing some repositories under `/etc/apk/repositories`, which contains these packages. you will need to add them before you could download them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to docker composer, how would I do that?

Comment: you can use the `RUN` keyword and add a step and use `echo "<Repo-URL>" > /etc/apk/repositories` . Also make sure the Repo-URL is still valid. if not you can use the steps from first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186008/how-to-add-alpine-linux-repositories-when-their-domain-is-expired

Comment: Is it a problem wiith the repo's? When I try the links in my browser both end up downloading a APKINDEX file. So they seem ok, right? `#0 0.442 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                      
#0 0.699 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz`

Comment: I am leaning towards saying that some repos where the packages are available might be missing and they need to be added. trying to download them directly from browser does not require such dependencies.  you could also alternatively download these packages manually and copy them over while building an image but that will require you to know the exact version dependencies